# Hide table header if there is no column attribute - Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here is a index.html.erb. How do I hide the table header, such as Remark, with a method when no records exists in remark attribute column? Preferably without using JavaScript.

index.html.erb

```
<table id = "kola" class="table listing text-center">
                <% has_remark = collection_has_remark?(@aslani361s) %>
                <thead>
                    <tr class="tr-head">
                        <td>Date</td>
                        <td>Description</td>
                        <td>Amount</td>
                        <td>Discount</td>
                        <td>Paid</td>
                        <td>Balance</td>
                        <td>DelnDel</td>
                        <% if has_remark %>
                        <td>Remark</td>
                        <% end %>
                        <td>Hide</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
</table>
```

However I am able to hide the remark attribute values like as below ;

_aslani361.html.erb

```
<% if aslani361.remark.present? -%>
    <td class="col-1"><%= aslani361.remark %></td>
<% end %>
```

aslani361s_helper.rb

```
module Aslani361sHelper
    def collection_has_remark?(collection)
        collection.each do |aslani361|
            if aslani361.remark.present?
                return true
            end
        end
    end
end
```

aslani361.rb

```
class Aslani361 < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

Any suggestions are most welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: can't you do the same thing you did to hide the remark attribute values? just wrap the Remark header in an if statement

Comment: can you post your models? Without knowing where remarks are stored, how they relate to other models, it's nearly impossible to come up with the code you would use to check the entire column.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How do I use the if statement to wrap the Remark header?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I posted my model.Please have a look and guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to hide the column because no records in your array has the remark value, you can do something like this:

Define a method in your helper module file for the controller:

```
def collection_has_remark?(collection)
  collection.each do |record|
    if record.remark.preset?
      return true
    end
  end
end
```

Then use it in the view

```
<% has_remark = collection_has_remark?(@records) %>

<thead>
    <tr class="tr-head">
        <td>Date</td>
        <td>Description</td>
        <td>Amount</td>
        <td>Discount</td>
        <td>Paid</td>
        <td>Balance</td>
        <% if has_remark %>
          <td>Remark</td>
        <% end %>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

Then use the same if statement inside your loop. Personally I think it's important to leave an empty column, so users know for sure it doesn't have one.

Comment: Thank you for your great reply.Unfortunately I get this error undefined method `collection_has_remark' for #<#<Class:0x00000007937590>:0x00000007501ed0>.

Comment: That was a typo on my part, sorry. Add the ? at the end of the method name in your view. Should be: `collection_has_remark?(@records)`. Updated my answer

Comment: Thank you for your reply again.Unfortunately I get this error "undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: if record.remark.preset? or if record.remark.present?

Comment: Can't I use something like, <% unless @aslani361s.collect{|p| p.remark}.uniq == [0] %> I used this before to hide when all values goes to  zero.Please guide.

Comment: @records was a pseudo variable on my part, as i had no idea what the name of the variable was you used in your code. Switch it to @aslani361s if that contains your records. My first solution was actually using a `.map(&:remark).compact.any?`, but figured that adds an extra loop which is really not needed. So I gave you a solution that uses one loop, plus it's good to know one can use helper methods to keep logic out of the view.

Comment: Thanks. I used @aslani361s but still unable to hide table header and do i still need to use <% if !aslani361.remark.blank? -%> ?

Comment: For the header, you need to use `has_remark`, for the row you can use either `has_remark` or check the field itself with .blank?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121776/discussion-between-muhammad-yaseen-and-agmcleod).

Comment: I have updated post again please have a look. Still not getting the desired result, I don't know where lies the problem?